# Return all possible index parameters

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I am working with C# and Crystal Reports library. I have a method that gets the SQL query for a specified parameters as shown below;

```
pi.GetIndexParameters()))[0].CommandText;
```

My issue is that once a report has more than one query - how can I find the number of indexes (queries) the report has and return each SQL query then?

```
//Returns SQL query based on index parameter
public string readSqlQuery(ReportDocument rd)
     {
         if (!rd.IsLoaded)
             throw new ArgumentException("Please ensure that the reportDocument has been loaded");
         PropertyInfo pi = rd.Database.Tables.GetType().GetProperty("RasTables", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

         return ((dynamic)pi.GetValue(rd.Database.Tables, pi.GetIndexParameters()))[0].CommandText;
     }
```

If you need any further information, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. Get and save the returned IndexParameters in a list `// UNNECESSARY, you can skip this`
2. loop through the list and get every value/CommandText, stored in a new list
3. either concatenate the list into a single string and return it OR
4. return the list of strings

If you're gonna go for 3, i assume you'd want the results from all the queries together?
Then make sure you make a `UNION ALL` on your queries...
Example:

`SELECT t.id, t.name, t.date FROM table t WHERE <some condition>
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.date FROM table t WHERE <some other condition>
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.date FROM table t WHERE <some third condition>`

So you're basically concatenating the queries with a "UNION ALL" and get a single result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply on this.  Your top suggestion is what I'll probably go for as there is hundreds of reports with multiple queries.  It would take us ages to update each report into a single query.  I'll get a chance later on today to work on this so I'll try the list way.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry now - just looking at your first point.  Go and save the returned index parameters in a list.  The trouble I am having is figuring out how to do this.  Once I have the the index parameters in a list I am okay to go from there.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric Sorry, it would seem that step 1 is unnecessary, because you get all your IndexParameters in one step.
So you basically only have to take the results of GetValue and loop through, not just take the first one with ``[0]``.
No need for the first loop.

Comment: Ah I see.  Let me give it a shot when I get a chance today and I'll post my attempt on the thread.  Thank you again!